# How to update url nodejs when xml file change in javascript?

Tags: javascript, xml, node.js

the code works , but I wanted you updated from when the xml changes , without using the Timeut or Interval

```
app.get('/prove', function (req, res) {
    testxml("1");
    res.end('OK \n');
});


testxml = function (num) {
request({
    uri:'urlXml',
    method: "GET"
}, function (err, res2, body) {
 ......
```

Comment: I'm a little confused by what you are asking. Do you want res.end to fire after testxml?

Comment: I wish that when it changes my xml ,
The url " localhost:port /prove " automatically change...
for not using:
 setInterval(function() { 
         textxml("1"); 
     }, 60000)

Comment: So you want to change the url on the client?

Comment: the url print the xml file.  I want that when the xml changes, the url to update itself .. sorry if I have explained myself badly :)

Comment: No worries. One problem is that your testxml function uses request which makes it asynchronous, so node is calling res.end before testxml returns. If you are instead trying to change the url of your browser/client you need to use client side javascript.

Comment: thanks a lot !! Could you give me an example ?

Comment: for which answer? The asynchronous or client side?

Answer (score 0):

So the question being asked here is really: How do I make sure that the response is sent after the XML updates when the XML is updated in a request?

One way of solving this is by rewriting the testxml function to take a callback function and calling res.end in that.

```
app.get('/prove', function (req, res) {
  testxml("1", function(){
    res.end('OK \n');
  });
});


testxml = function (num, callback) {
  request({
    uri:'urlXml',
    method: "GET"
  }, function (err, res2, body) {
    ...
    callback()
  })
}
```